# LibGdx - How do I take input from my player, but also be able to take input from a stage

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Basically I have a game, where the player on the map is handled by wasd using an InputProcessor. My problem is I cant have 2 input processors at the same time, and to me it seems as if I need 2. What is the suggested way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very common case and that's why libGDX has an [`InputMultiplexer`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputMultiplexer.html) to forward the events to both `InputProcessors`.

You basically use it like this:

```
InputProcessor inputProcessorOne = new CustomInputProcessor();
InputProcessor inputProcessorTwo = stage;
InputMultiplexer inputMultiplexer = new InputMultiplexer();
inputMultiplexer.addProcessor(inputProcessorOne);
inputMultiplexer.addProcessor(inputProcessorTwo);
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(inputMultiplexer);
```

See [libgdx multiple objects implementing InputProcessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23546544/libgdx-multiple-objects-implementing-inputprocessor) for a bit more detailed explanation.