# libgdx InputMultiplexer not working with dialog

Tags: java, libgdx

I work on a libgdx project. On my GameScreen, I have 3 class:

- one for the game render
- one for the buttons and arrows listener
- and a last for a dialog. This dialog is display at the end of the game.

I need to have an inputProcessor on the button, on the arrows and on the dialog. The button class manages the buttons and the arrows. Here is an abstract of my button class:

```
public class ButtonRenderer implements InputProcessor {
      public Stage stage;
      public ButtonRenderer(){
          stage = new Stage();
          stage.addActor(someButtons);
     }

     //inputProcessor
     @Override
     public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
         //do something
         return true;
     }

}
```

For the dialog, it's another class which does not implement InputProcessor but which have a stage:

```
public class ScoreRenderer{
    public Stage stage;
    public ScoreRenderer(){
        stage = new Stage();
        Dialog dialog = new CustomDialog();
        dialog.show(stage);
    }
}
```

So now, I want to set the buttonRenderer.stage, the buttonRenderer and the scoreRenderer.stage as InputProcessor. To do it, in my GameScreen I have:

```
@Override
public void show() {
    buttonRenderer = new ButtonRenderer(game);
    scoreRenderer = new ScoreRenderer(game);

    InputMultiplexer multiplexer = new InputMultiplexer();
    multiplexer.addProcessor(buttonRenderer.stage);
    multiplexer.addProcessor(buttonRenderer);
    multiplexer.addProcessor(scoreRenderer.stage);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(multiplexer);
}
```

But it doesn't work, arrows and buttons are not clikable and dialog is clikable just one time.

Edit: When I comment the line `dialog.show(stage);`, all works fine! How can
I show my dialog and keep the multiplexer available??

Comment: The boolean return values for the inputs are for indicating whether the input event was processed by this handler. Are you returning true even if the event isn't processed for any of your input handlers?

Comment: Yes, I always return true

Comment: did u write Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(somearrows) in your  ButtonRenderer  class?

Comment: no because if I do that, it will remove all others processors. But the arrows's listener is buttonRenderer, and I add it to the multiplexer: `multiplexer.addProcessor(buttonRenderer); `

Comment: I hope this will be helpful solve your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23546544/libgdx-multiple-objects-implementing-inputprocessor